# How to terminate python script when the node is shutdown

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using this idiom for checking that the node in my python script is working

```
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
   do some work
```

but when I kill the node with rosnode kill the while loop does not exit.
I suppose rosnode kill triggers the flag associated with is_shutdown(), but maybe I'm wrong.

Could anyone please clarify me on the issue of finishing nodes and the processes that hold them properly? I've checked previous answers, but maybe I've missed a complete example with code on how to catch and handle the related signals.

Thank you very much in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38083/how-to-terminate-python-script-when-the-node-is-shutdown/) by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That should work.

Node termination notification can be quite slow to arrive. Maybe you didn't wait long enough.

If you invoke a bunch of nodes using `roslaunch`, typing `^C` in that terminal sends the interrupt signal to all of them fairly quickly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-06**:
roslaunch sends a sigint I think. rosnode kill uses an xmlrpc request. But anyway, I just did a test and can confirm that the above while loop is perfectly fine for both, C-c and the xmlrpc request.